# App Fabric support for multisubnetfailover

Tags: appfabric

We have added multisubnetfailover=true to our App Fabric connection strings and get a "keyword not supported error" in App Fabric. I cannot find any articles describing this and wanted to know if anyone has dealt with this issue (and hopefully resolved it)?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of .Net you're using, you might have to install [this update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2654347/EN-US) - also make sure your connection string is [pointing to the Availabilty Group Listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205662%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If you upgrade a SqlClient application that currently uses database
>   mirroring to a multi-subnet scenario, you should remove the Failover
>   Partner connection property and replace it with MultiSubnetFailover
>   set to True and replace the server name in the connection string with
>   an availability group listener.